# How to send custom header in flutter http post request

Tags: http, flutter, dart

There is http package in my flutter project. I want to send a post request with custom header. Here is my code snippet. it will make clear my problem using http for custom header. It always runs else statement means the response type is not 200 and it gives me the error provided Invalid token. but on a post man, it works fine

```
Map data = {
    'user_fullname': _name,
    'user_address': _address,
    'user_mobile': _phone,
  };
  var tokenData = {
    'User_token': token,
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  };

  final response = await http.post(url, body: data, headers: tokenData);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print(response.body);
  } else {
    print(response.body);
  }
```

[Postman Testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJG8m.png)

Comment: My bet is that your server is incorrectly requiring that the `User_token` header have an upper case `U`. (Dart will lower case it as it sends it.) Try your postman request again, but with a lowercase `user_token` and see what happens.

Comment: @RichardHeap good point, but wouldn't that affect Postman request as well?

Comment: same issue on postman when i sent with lower case

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing you're passing invalid types to the post request. (headers must be `Map<String, String>` (i'm not sure what is dart inferring from `tokenData` at runtime), body can be dynamic, etc.)

```
  final String url = 'YOUR_API_URL';
  final Map<String, String> tokenData = {
   "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
   "user_token": token
  };
  final Map<String, String> data = { //is _phone a String?
    'user_fullname': _name,
    'user_address': _address,
    'user_mobile': _phone,
  };

  final Response response = await post(url, headers: tokenData, body: data);

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print(response.body);
  } else {
    print(response.body);
  }
}
```

the body can only be a `String`, a `List<int>` or a `Map<String, String>`

as descibed at https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/Client/post.html

Answer (score 1):

A little late to this but just got the same issue. 
What I realised on my side is that Headers for flutter HTTP clients are case insensitive. They automatically lowercase it https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16665. 
Some servers receive case sensitive headers.

Postman sends a case sensitive header thats why User_token is properly received.

Solution wise try :https://pub.dev/packages/alt_http

Answer (score 0):

In your case must use try... catch exception.

And you can refer the below one.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

And http request is...

```
  var client = new http.Client();
    try{
       var response = await client.post(
         "Your Url", 
         headers: {"User_token" : token /*, ...etc*/},
         body : {
           'user_fullname': _name,
           'user_address': _address,
           'user_mobile': _phone,
         }
       );
      if(response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201){
          //enter your code
      }
    } on Exception catch (err){
       print("Error : $err");
    }
```

I hope help you.

[Authorization image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJNKj.png)

Comment: Thanks for your response but still i am getting the same error :(

Comment: yes of course 

I/flutter ( 7261): {"result":{"status":false,"message":"Provided invalid token"}}

Comment: please see in the authorization link in the question section

Comment: Hmm... Thanks for you reply. I have one ask. Can you share your postman request. If it not security, please send me the postman request file. I will test in here. And I will try my self. After complete, i will provide the code.